# Python method takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python

I see where similar questions have been asked before but I don't see how to apply that to my situation.  Here's the python code:

```
def __init__(self):
    print("running")
    #set the glade file
    self.gladefile = "/home/crokett/Data/Projects/Glade/MultiTerm.glade"
    print("Gladefile is: self.gladefile")
    #self.wTree = gtk.glade.XML(self.gladefile)
    #try gtk file
    builder = gtk.Builder()
    builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
    builder.connect_signals(self)

    #Get the Main Window, and connect the "destroy" event
    self.window = builder.get_object("mainWindow")
    if (self.window):
       print("Found main window")
       self.window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
       self.window.show()

def on_loadButton_clicked(self):
     self.filechooser=builder.get_object("fileChooser")
     self.filechooser.show()
```

With the above code, I get the error message that

```
TypeError: on_loadButton_clicked(self) takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I originally had  on_LoadButton_Clicked defined as:

```
  on_loadButton_clicked()
```

but I got the error message:

```
 TypeError: on_loadButton_clicked) takes exactly 0 argument (2 given)
```

I can post the XML if I need to.  the on_loadButton_Clicked method is supposed to open a file chooser dialog

I saw posts that said I needed to define the method with (self) but I'mm not sure what the other argument would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to very little searching, I've learned that `on_loadButton_clicked` should take two arguments. The first is `self`, and the second will be a widget. Just add a second parameter to the function, and chances are you won't actually need to use it.

Comment: `self` doesn't need to be passed in method calls: something like `def set_height(self, height)` would be called with `myobject.set_height(5.5)`.

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear. I'm referring to the function definition (`def on_loadButton_clicked...`), not where it's called from. The actual function call is done by the GTK library, which passes a widget through as the only argument. However, `self` is an implicit argument, so your function needs `self` and another parameter for the widget being passed in.

Comment: @Ken thanks.  I built the gui in question in Glade. I am still learning Glade (and Python) and the method name was suggested by Glade.  Apparently it's a pre-defined methond in Python?  I thought Glade was just suggesting it based on the name of the button widget.

Comment: I've never used Glade myself, but if you check in MultiTerm.glade, it gives descriptions of the UI using XML. For your button, it has a property that should look like `<signal name="pressed" handler="on_loadButton_clicked" swapped="no"/>`. The name used there must match the function in your code, and this connection is made when you call `builder.connect_signals(self)`.